# apt-get doesn't find ROS packages at all

Tags: ros, download, raspbian, begginer-tutorials, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried running `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-tutorials ros-indigo-geometry-tutorials ros-indigo-rviz ros-indigo-rosbash ros-indigo-rqt-tf-tree` but it outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-tutorials
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-geometry-tutorials
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rviz
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rosbash
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rqt-tf-tree
```

`apt-get` seems to be able to download other things such as `nmap` but the ROS packages simply are un-locatable. Any ideas? I'm pretty new to Raspbian (I'm on a RPi) and feel a bit at a loss.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221166/apt-get-doesn%27t-find-ros-packages-at-all/) by [Tetrachromat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25121/tetrachromat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-11-18**:
did you run `sudo apt-get update` beforehand?

**Comment by [Tetrachromat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25121/tetrachromat/) on 2015-11-18**:
Yes. I did it, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Raspberry Pi does not use the same binary format as standard desktop computers, so the standard ROS installation setup does not work.

Have a look at the [ROS Indigo on Raspberry Pi instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi).

If you're using a Raspberry Pi 2, you can also install Ubuntu on it, and use the Ubuntu for armhf instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tetrachromat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25121/tetrachromat/) on 2015-11-18**:
I did run the setup from that installation page. Roscore does actually run, but specifically there's a problem downloading packages.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-11-18**:
Which installation page? I linked to two.

**Comment by [Tetrachromat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25121/tetrachromat/) on 2015-11-18**:
First link.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-11-18**:
The first link describes an installation of ROS from sources, and the final section (5.2) describes how to add additional packages from source. You can't use apt-get to add packages to a source install, and the apt packages aren't available on Raspbian.

**Comment by [LukeH](https://answers.ros.org/users/25639/lukeh/) on 2016-01-20**:
Have you had any luck with this?  I have been having the same issue for several days now.  This is the first part of the tutorial that hasn't worked.  Can we just download each package from the source instead?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-20**:
@LukeH: the answer is pretty clear - if you're following the from-source installation on the Raspberry Pi, you can't use apt to install additional packages. Use the instructions in section 5.2 for installing additional packages from source.